# Manager gives a queryset from files and not from a database

Tags: django, file, django-queryset

I would like to override the manager class in order to allow content data to be loaded from text files (here on of "/one directory/myPrefix_*") into content field instead of from a database table.

```
class Things(model.Models):
    file    = CharField(max_length = 25, primary key = True)
    content = TextField()
    objects = myManager("/one directory/", "myPrefix_")
```

I would appreciate to use this class in the admin site, if possible.

Is my wild dream possible?

Comment: "allow content data to be loaded from text files"...does that mean you want to use text files *instead of* a database backend?

Comment: Yes.  I know that a data base is more modern and flexible.  But since the final result must be written into files the data base duplicates the values of the 'content' field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would solve this by renaming objects to _objects, and then creating a property function to load the data. Something like the code below should do what you need...

```
class Things(model.Models):
    file    = CharField(max_length = 25, primary key = True)
    content = TextField()
    _objects = CharField(max_length = 50)

    @property
    def objects(self):
        return load_content_from("/one directory/myPrefix_" + self._objects)
```

If you want to see the content from the files in the admin site then you'll probably need to create your own field type (see http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/db/models/fields).

Comment: First, thanks for your answer.

But in this case, Thinks.objects.all() would not be accessible anymore because the manager would have been replaced.  I guess 'content' should rather be given by a callable @property.  

'content' is a read_only property, and a new field representing the file name is added.

Much simpler than a custom manager!